# Pushing Data From Spreadsheets Using App Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, integration, slack-api

So I'm trying to write a script on Google App Scripts that does the following:
On a spreadsheet with several columns and rows, whenever someone checks a checkbox on a cetain row, push the data existing on that same row, but on a different column, into a Slack message.

**For instance, let's say A1 in my spreadsheet is 'XX02' and Q1 is a checkbox. If someone comes and checks Q1, I want to send an automated message saying "XX02 done". **

Here's what I got so far:

```
var url = "slack url"

function onEdit(e){

var column = e.getColumn;
var row = e.getRow
var newValue = e.value; 
var oldValue = e.oldValue; 

var payload = {
      'text' : CELLVALUE + " changed from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue  + ":white_check_mark:"
    };
var params = {
      'method' : 'post',
      'contentType' : 'application/json',
      'payload' : JSON.stringify(payload)
    };
  
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)

}
```

So of course, "CELLVALUE" is a placeholder there cause I have no idea how to get that value. Because I need it to work regardless of whatever box I check.

So far, what I get on Slack using this code is a message saying this "undefined changed from undefined to TRUE".

Thanks in advance to anyone who can give me a hint.

Comment: You are changing the value of checkbox. But you want to get the value in another column which is not changing. Your Slack messaging is confusing. What do you want to do?

Comment: Well, all columns in the same row have information regarding the same project (it's a project management spreadsheet), columnn Q1 is a checkbox and A1 includes the project number, and the same goes for Q2-A2, Q3-A3 and so on. Basically, checking the box in column Q is saying the project in that row is ready to be delivered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the target column is left next to that of the checkbox:

```js
var range = e.range;
var cell = range.offset(0, -1);
var CELLVALUE = cell.getValue();
```

Reference:
[offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset)

Comment: Oh thank you so so so much! This worked like a charm, it was 16 columns to the left, so I just adjusted that value and that was it! I'm sorry that my question was so unclear, I'm rather new to programming and extremely new to App Scripts. Thanks again!